How do I copy several worksheets into a target workbook with VBA while retaining all formatting and pasting only values?
I'm a total VBA beginner and I've looked for lots of forum entries for VBA codes for copying over worksheets that apply to my case. My goal is

That I can copy four specific sheets ("Dashboard", "Similar jobs", "Comparable jobs", "Salary distributions") of my source workbook over into a single target workbook ("Report.xlsx")
and that all formatting remains the same and that figures are copied as well, while only formulas in cells are replaced by their values.
Then there is only one sheet of the four ("Dashboard") that displays text boxes with values in them that stem from cell references from another sheet ("Parameters") in the source workbook that is not copied over. Here the values in the text boxes should also be pasted only as values
The code should be executeable from the source workbook and the path of the target workbook is "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Tool-Print".

One code that I found worked fairly well for having only two sheets to copy, though it copies everything into an entirely new workbook and not a target one. And if you add more sheets to this code, the remaining sheets each opened in their own seperate new workbooks. It looks like this:
Sub Copy_Worksheets()
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Worksheets("Sheet name").Copy
        ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AG225").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
        .Worksheets("Sheet name(2)").Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AG225").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

I've also worked now with this new suggestion which copies all required worksheets, but still doesn't save the cell contents as values and I'm not sure how to add ".PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues" to this code:
Sub Copy_Worksheets()
    With ThisWorkbook
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet name", "Sheet name(2)", "Sheet name(3)", "Sheet name(4)")).Copy Before:=Workbooks("Report.xlsx").Sheets(1)
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

If someone could help me figure out how to define the target workbook in this code, how to define the specific number of sheets and which exact sheets are copied over, I'd very much appreciate it.

Hello, the vba code produced automatically is awful. I assume you want to copy from one workbook with a file name to another workbook with a file name.

For example: Thisworkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet13", "Sheet3", "Results")).Copy Before:=Workbooks("Target.xlsx"). Sheets(1)

1.) Do you know the names of the 4 sheets or is there a special way how you plan to identify them? Let's say the workbook with the sheets is the Source and the other is the Target. 2.) Where is this code located, in the Source or the Target? 3.) What is the name of the workbook that does not have the code (e.g. Other.xlsx)? 4.) If this workbook will be closed, what is its path (e.g. C:\Test)? Please share the answers and more details by editing your post.

@Tarik yes exactly.

@VBasic2008 1) Yes I do. The names also won't change throughout time. 2) In the source. 3) "Report.xlsx" 4) "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Tool-Print"

@TimWilliams This worked out great, but now there is still the issue of pasting all cell contents only as values and I'm not sure how to integrate the ".PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues" part properly.

For example:
Dim arr, targetWb as Workbook, sourceWb as Workbook, el

arr = Array("Sheet13", "Sheet3", "Results")   'sheets to be copied over

Set sourceWb  = ThisWorkbook                  'for example
Set targetWb = Workbooks("Target.xlsx")

sourceWb.Sheets(arr).Copy Before:=targetWb.Worksheets(1)

For Each el in arr      'for each copied sheet...
    With targetWb.sheets(el).UsedRange
        .Value = .Value 'convert any formulas to values
    End with
next el


This worked out really well, thanks a lot! All cell contents now contain only numbers, but I realized that shape elements like text boxes are not pasted as values but retain their cell references. Would you also have a solution for these?

If you can edit your question and add the exact steps to replicate one of your text boxes I can take a look.

shape elements in the copied sheets have references to the copy or to the original of the Sheet?

@Max to the original sheet

@TimWilliams I'm not sure if this is specific enough what I edited in the post, but the cell formulas in the text boxes are rather simple like "=Parameter!$T$7"

Copy Sheets to Another Workbook
Did you know?

Copying sheets in one go keeps the formulas that should link among the worksheets working i.e. they don't link to the source workbook as they would if each sheet was copied separately (not relevant here since only values are required).
On the other hand, the sheets are copied in the same order as the order in the source workbook which is not necessarily the order in the array.

The Code

Not tested!

Sub CreateReport()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const DST_SUB_PATH As String = "\Desktop\Tool-Print\"
    Const DST_FILE_NAME As String = "Report.xlsx"
    Dim SHEET_NAMES As Variant: SHEET_NAMES = Array( _
        "Dashboard", "Similar jobs", "Comparable jobs", "Salary distributions")
    Const TEXTBOX_SHEET_NAME As String = "Dashboard"
    
    ' Build the paths.
    
    Dim dFolderPath As String:
    dFolderPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & DST_SUB_PATH
    Dim dFilePath As String: dFilePath = dFolderPath & DST_FILE_NAME
    
    ' Reference the destination workbook.
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Set dwb = Workbooks(DST_FILE_NAME)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If dwb Is Nothing Then ' the workbook is closed
        Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(dFilePath)
    Else ' a workbook with the name is open
        If StrComp(dwb.FullName, dFilePath, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then ' wrong!
            MsgBox "Another file named """ & dwb.Name & " is already open!", _
                vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        'Else ' the correct workbook is open; do nothing
        End If
    End If
    
    ' Reference the source workbook and copy the specified sheets
    ' after the last destination sheet.
    ' Convert the formulas in the copied worksheets to values.
    ' Also, remove the links from all text boxes in the text-box sheet.
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook
    swb.Sheets(SHEET_NAMES).Copy After:=dwb.Sheets(dwb.Sheets.Count)
    
    Dim dsh As Object, ole As Object, SheetName As Variant
    
    For Each SheetName In SHEET_NAMES
        Set dsh = dwb.Sheets(SheetName)
        If TypeOf dsh Is Worksheet Then
            ' Convert formulas to values.
            With dsh.UsedRange
                .Value = .Value
            End With
            ' Remove links from text boxes.
            If StrComp(dsh.Name, TEXTBOX_SHEET_NAME, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                For Each ole In dsh.OLEObjects
                    If TypeName(ole.Object) = "TextBox" Then
                        ole.LinkedCell = vbNullString
                    End If
                Next ole
            'Else ' it's not the text-box sheet; do nothing
            End If
        'Else ' it's a chart; do nothing
        End If
    Next SheetName
            
    ' Save and close.
    
    'dwb.SaveAs "Some Path", xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    'dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' just got saved
            
    ' Inform.
            
    MsgBox "Report created.", vbInformation
            
End Sub


This code seems to work mostly, but the text boxes still retain their original reference formulas in the target workbook. Otherwise it seems to work well! (Sorry for the late reply, it has been a busy week).
